# Working with date in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have many companies each one have a opening date and a closing date ex :

```
Company  Open   Close
```

---

```
A        08.00  22.00     (close in the **same** day)
B        10.00  02.00     (close in the **second** day)
C        14.00  03.00     (close in the **second** day)
```

On the web page the user must see a list of the companies and show the status of each one (**open** or **close**) depending on the current time (SERVER TIME)

THE PROBLEM :
when the company open and close in the same day ( A ) it's easy to get the status
in the following algorithm : `isOpen = (NOW > OpenTime AND NOW < ClosingTime)`
, but if the company **open in day 1** and **close in day 2** ( B , C ) if the user check the page at 1.00 the company B will appear closed (because `(1.00 > 10.00 AND 1.00 < 02.00)` is **False** ) but in real time its opened.

How can I resolve this issue (when the closing time day is different than the opening time day)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution I can think of would be to check if the close time listed is less than the open time and add 24 hours, and check against that value

```
isOpen = (NOW > OpenTime AND NOW < (ClosingTime < OpeningTime ? ClosingTime + 24.00 : ClosingTime)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the *opening time* is later than the *closing time*, then reverse your test.

Comment: how does this work if the current time is 12.00 for company C... they are closed, but if you reverse the times, then the test would say it's open

Comment: There are edge cases. That's part of solving the problem.

Comment: I think he had the problem solved within reason, he was coming to SO for help with his edge case, so I'd argue that was exactly part of solving the problem

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood it right there is the following algorithm:

When open time is less than close time: `isOpen = now > openTime && now < closeTime`.

Otherwise, `isOpen = now > openTime || now < closeTime`.

```
TimeSpan nowTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(11);
TimeSpan openTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(8);
TimeSpan closeTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);

bool isOpened = openTime < closeTime
                    ? (nowTime > openTime && nowTime < closeTime)
                    : (nowTime > openTime || nowTime < closeTime);
```

Note: `TimeSpan` struct has been used for time interval representation, but `double` may be used also (by simple replacing).

Comment: Because **only time** is needed, `DateTime` structure provides both date and time. My code uses the fact: *close date is the second day* when the close time is less than open time. But you can use `DateTime` with this code also. :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do you:

```
class Company
{
  public string   Name         { get ; set ; }

  // represents the time-of-day at which the company opens (e.g. 08:00, 14:00, etc.)
  public TimeSpan OpensAtTime  { get ; set ; }

  // represents the time-of-day at which the company closes (e.g.17:00, 08:00, etc. )
  public TimeSpan ClosesAtTime { get ; set ; }

  public bool IsOpen()
  {
    DateTime instant          = DateTime.Now ;
    DateTime Today            = instant.Date ;
    TimeSpan totalOpenHours   = ( this.ClosesAtTime - this.OpensAtTime ).Duration() ;
    DateTime openTimeToday    = Today + this.OpensAtTime ;
    DateTime closingTimeToday = openTimeToday + totalOpenHours ;
    bool     isOpen           = instant >= openTime && instant <= closingTime ;

    return isOpen ;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression you gave applies only when OpenTime is less than closing time, so:

```
isOpen = (OpenTime < ClosingTime AND NOW >= OpenTime AND NOW < ClosingTime) OR (NOW >= OpenTime OR NOW < ClosingTime)
```