# How to handle opening and close time in Python?

Tags: python

I have open and close times of restaurants in this format in the database in 2 columns

```
opencol:00:00 closecol:24:00 weekday:1, 
opencol:23:00,closecol:02:00 weekday:2 etc.
```

Some, restaurants have 2 records for the same week day  like

```
opencol:11:00 closecol:14:00 weekday:1
opencol:16:00 closecol:23:00 weekday:1
```

My use case is to figure out based on current time, if a restaurant is open? How do I handle the above 2 scenarios?

Comment: Select rows with proper weekday and opencol < current time and closecol > current time? If found, restaurant is open.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Working with date in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317208/working-with-date-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) module provides all that you need.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 18, 20, 38, 53, 271145)
```

You can get the current weekday with [`datetime.datetime.weekday`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.weekday).

```
>>> now.weekday()
5
```

Fetch the database values and put them into [`datetime.time`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.time) objects (you work out how, it shouldn't be hard to figure out; `strptime` will probably be what you need).

Some sample data:

```
>>> opening_time = datetime.time(11, 0, 0, 0)
>>> closing_time = datetime.time(14, 0, 0, 0)
```

Then, compare the times:

```
>>> opening_time < now.time() < closing_time
False
```

It's not open at present (because it's 8:38pm).

Naturally, it will get more complex once you need to compare multiple values, but that's a simple matter of iteration; more difficult will be where you have values spanning multiple days as your sample data seems to indicate you may have. But those aren't very hard to figure out once you've got the basics in.

Note that this deals with it all in Python; most use cases (not quite sure about the weekday business, though with a quick search several at least seem to support it) should be able to be satisfied at the database level, but only if you specify what that (I mean the database that you're using) is...

Comment: You definitely answered more verbosely than me. Would the `opening_time < now.time()` part not be better as a `<=` though? Given that a store's opening time is inclusive, and the closing time is exclusive to what you search on?

Comment: @asmodai: I wouldn't consider that it mattered; times include milliseconds. If you wanted to, though, you could.

Comment: @John: not true. You just need to get the format string correct; 24-hour hour is `%H`.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I meant,  datetime.datetime.strptime("24:00","%I:%M"), gives error

Comment: @John: that's because `24:00` isn't a valid 24-hour time. It's `00:00` by definition.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan good solution, there is one issue worth mentioning though. It would not work if the place is open from 17:00 till 02:00, because of 02:00 being next day. and also if the place is open 24hrs 06:00 - 06:00. I think good solution would be to add date to the closing time

Answer (score 0):

Get the current time (wrap it up in a nice function/method of course):

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.now()
weekday = int(d.strftime("%w"))
hours = int(d.strftime("%H")
minutes = int(d.strftime("%M")
```

And then with a SQL query do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM times WHERE restaurant = [id] AND weekday = [weekday] AND opencol <= [hours] AND closecol < [hours];
```

Depending on the rest of your data, you might need to use the minutes as well, but with the data you provided you can shortcircuit that case.

Comment: Using `strftime` is the wrong thing to do here; `d.weekday`, `d.hour` and `d.minute` are the values you want.

Comment: Yeah, was reminded of them again
 when I saw your answer. The downside of having to do much Java and C# in recent months.